# How to create a "Configuration Information [Automatically generated, do not change]"?

Tags: bash, configuration

I was reading [a thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-07/msg00044.html) on the [bug-bash mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/) and saw:

```
Configuration Information [Automatically generated, do not change]:
Machine: x86_64
OS: linux-gnu
...
```

Since this "Configuration Information" header appears in [other threads](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-07/msg00033.html) I assume there is some kind of tool to get it automatically.

However, I tried with `dmidecode`, `lscpu` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` or `cat /proc/meminfo` and none of them matches this content.

How does this *Configuration Information* get created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool that creates that report is called `bashbug` and it's part of `bash` package.
See `man bashbug` for more details.